# Polygonal darkness appearing in render

Tags: rendering, light

I am following this [BlenderGuru tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/videos/how-to-make-a-realistic-asteroid/) on making an asteroid and when it comes to rendering the scene I get an unwanted "shadow". The shadow starts to appear in frame 36 of the render (but is clearer in frame 40) and i do not know what i have done wrong. Here is the [blend file](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/23107).

The effect described here is clearly visible in the right top corner, like a polygonal darkness.

[image]

Comment: @zeffii followed you advice (I presume you meant in the material settings) and it worked to a certain extent(it removed the unwanted shadow) but I lost the cloud texture on the space backdrop. is there any way to do what you have suggested and keep the texture visable. cheers.

Comment: to make sure this question will be relevant to people even after the .blend file is removed from pasteall.org I suggest you adapt it, include a screenshot (or include my screenshots). If you don't there is a possibility that this question will end up being removed.

Answer (score 4):

**Two ways to solve this**

**1**  scale down the `space_backdrop` sphere so it fits inside the camera clipping bounds

**2**
Set the viewing mode to shaded (press Z again), and you can clearly see it's not a shadow but a feature of the clipping plane. Modify the *Clipping End* parameter (In *Properties > Camera Settings*) to be large enough to fit the whole scene.

[image]

[image]

it's difficult to see in wireframe mode:
[image]

to visualize the clipping plane, you enable 'limits' in the Display panel of the camera. View the scene from the side and zoom out to see how the limits indicator behaves as you adjust the `End` value

[image]